# Android:Bitmap out of memory error

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I have a database file which contents 1500 images as blob content.I need to decode it to use it on grid view. But whenever I decode it by using this code:

```
Bitmap bit_clueimage=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(clueimage, 0,clueimage.length,option)
```

my GC Starts increasing and it goes out of memory.I tried to recycle it by using:

```
bit_clueimage.recycle();
```

but it doesn't worked for me. i am stuck to these problem please help me.

Comment: you need to load scaled down bitmap into memory. see here http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html how to handle large bitmaps...

Comment: I wondering you crating multiple bitmap instances  (not recycling properly). would please post the code snip where you need help.I had same earlier.

Comment: @ RDC: i have an image view on an activity with one button.when i click on button it should decode an image and display on image view.after showing 16 images i need move to another activity.after some activities i have to come on same activity.this continues until i finishes my all images.but somewhere between 300 to 400 image decoding i get out of memory due to continues increase in GC

Comment: @GopalRao : I sacled down my images still my GC doesn't stop increasing its size

Comment: use Univeral Image Loader library https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader. this may help you...

Answer (score 0):

Hi Use Picasso Library :

http://square.github.io/picasso/

and For setting the image

Picasso.with(context).load("image.png").into("ImageVIew");